# Android app closes unexpectedly on AVD (Android Studio). (Logcat attached)

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, adb

I installed an app named textplus on android virtual device running android 6. I was able to complelte the registration process on the app but it crashes after that without any error messages. I have collected the log from logcat(adb). I am not familiar with android dev. so i am not able to pinpoint what the issue. but i feel like it has something to do with webview. [This is the log from adb](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/juvozobado.py)

Comment: Every crash has a corresponding stack trace in logcat. Check once again.

Comment: @NisanthReddy I have attached a link to the logcat. I am not able to understand what the problem is exactly. i am not an android dev.

Comment: Hi, What I meant is that this logcat is definitely not complete. Logcat keeps changing so the error might've escaped. So keep you logcat always open and then run the app. As soon as it crashed, you will see different messages in the logcat. Post them.

Comment: @NisanthReddy I cropped out the part from the log which i think is related to what happened. The first line is where the app started and the last line is where the app died, so i feel like the error could be in this. I am really skeptical about line 59 to 62.